# Swift - how to shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to shouldOverrideUrlLoading (Android) in Swift for IOS.  I want to capture the URL from a webview and not load that URL.  Is this possible with swift?  How would it be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using webview then use web view delegate method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` to return false for not loading the URL in webview. For eg.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if request.url?.absoluteString == "https://www.google.com" {
      return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out

```
func webView(UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType)
```

in UIWebViewDelegate ([UIWebViewDelegate Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate))

Set your view controller as the web view's delegate and return `false` in the method above to stop a url from loading in the web view.

Example:

```
class MyWebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if request.url?.absoluteString.contains("dontLoadMe") {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```